# How to install language on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm coding a program for iOS 11 swift3. I'm trying to code the application for it to install the proper language pack if it's not installed on the iPhone already. The app is a "Learn English" program. I want to make sure the user has Chinese input installed on the iOS device already. I was wondering if anyone out there know's anything class iOS library that need to use in order to get it to download the language package?

Comment: I dont think you can do it. I think the more reasonable way to do it is to have some tutorial screen to show user how to add Chinese input method with their iphone, for example, user can add new keyboard in Settings->General->Keyboards->Add new keyboard...

Comment: I'm going to have to edit my webpage and show them how to edit the input keyboard to install Chinese Language for the input.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit since it is not appropriate to completely redo your question after accepting an answer. If you have another issue (such as how to show an alert), you should post a new question specific to that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to add a keyboard programmatically. The user must do it by running the Settings app and going to General -> Keyboard -> Keyboards and selecting "Add New Keyboard...".

But you can detect if a certain keyboard is already installed or not. So you can check if the user has added a Chinese keyboard or not. If they haven't, you can show a message with instructions telling them how to add the keyboard.

```
var hasChinese = false
let keyboards = UITextInputMode.activeInputModes
for keyboard in keyboards {
    if let language = keyboard.primaryLanguage {
        if language.hasPrefix("zh") {
            hasChinese = true
        }
    }
}

if !hasChinese {
    // show message with instructions
}
```

You may wish to check for a specific Chinese keyboard instead of any Chinese keyboard. Adjust the check of `language` as needed.

Comment: I created a pop-up message, but for some reason not showing up.....     Message.createAlert(title: "Testing" , message: "Testing")          func createAlert (title:String, message:String)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil); print ("Message Alert UI Was Activated") }))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Comment: That's a completely different issue. Are you at least able to properly determine whether the user has the desired keyboard installed or not? If so, you should indicate that you question has been answered by accepting the answer. If you have a new issue you should post a new question.

Comment: I did a test with the code. I added and remove the chinese handwriting keyboard from iOS. The code is working way it's suppose to. I just need to implment the pop-up message saying to add chinese handwriting in iPhone settings.